# How to choose source (1080p,720p,480p) with MediaElementJS?

Tags: mediaelement.js

I have just found MediaElementJs and I must say it works excellent. Now, I was wondering how (or rather if) it would be possible to supply multiple media sources of the same video in different resolutions (1080p,720p,480p) and to have a button which lets the user choose between these sources (like the one Youtube uses). Does MediaElementJS come with such a function or do I have to write one myself in order to make it work?

Thanks in advance!